# Java, selenium ; How to get text in alt=" <span class="forthetest" > text</span>"?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**I can not get text from this:**

code is : `<area alt="menu <span class="forthetest"> text</span>">`

Anyone can help?

Comment: Where area tag ends ? share the full area tag and what is your desire output.

Comment: its in map tag. and end in this. I wanna get text string in this code.

Comment: Share the full map tag then , these things are required for diagnosis purpose

Comment: Where is your Java code? Why does it seem that `span` node is a part of `alt` attribute of `area` node? Share HTML sample as it is - don't make any simplifications/modifications

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided as:

```
<area alt="menu <span class="forthetest"> text</span>">
```

To extract the text **text** you can use the following solution:

```
String nodetext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//area[starts-with(@alt,'menu')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] textParts = nodetext.split("<|>");
System.out.println(textParts[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use the folowing code

```html
    <area alt="menu"><span> text</span></area>
```

Comment: I want to get text from this, i didn't write it.I think its about the css.

Comment: The question is related to get text from span tags , this is not the relevant answer!